# Is there a way of making a faster updating function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making an idle game to get my javascript skills better but i cant seem to find a way to update my numbers faster my current code is this

`<div id="plastic"></div>`

```
var plasticCount = setInterval(() => { 
    document.getElementById('plastic').innerHTML = plasticCount;
}, 1000);
```

This might not be the exact way I had it but it is close. The point I'm trying to say is that it updates here every second but it isn't fast enough for an idle game. I'm looking for a way to update it extremely quickly to update the number so it doesn't feel as slow

Comment: Depends what you want, you get update directly after you set the plastic amount instead of every second interval?

Comment: Why check every X seconds if the value has changed? You can just update the html directly when you change `plasticCount`

Comment: @JoelHarkes Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do here. Do you know a way of doing so?

Comment: Just `document.getElementById('plastic').innerHTML = plasticCount` after updating. You should cache `document.getElementById('plastic')` into a variable and use it instead of `document.getElementById('plastic')`. (Or you could use setters, but I don't think it's worth the trouble.)

Comment: why don't you just try `document.getElementById('plastic').text = plasticCount`

Comment: Code makes no sense since plasticCount is the setInterval id....

Comment: @epascarello Yes i know. ill fix that because im going off of memory here as i had scrapped that version to make a new one, im just trying to find a faster alternative to using setInterval

Comment: why use setTimeout? You can call the update code whenever you update the variable.

Comment: @epascarello  I didnt think of that...

Answer (score 1):

Just change `1000` to a smaller number:

```
var plasticCount = setInterval(() => { 
    document.getElementById('plastic').innerHTML = plasticCount;
}, 10);
```

And this will help CPU usage some:

```
const count = document.getElementById('plastic')
var plasticCount = setInterval(() => { 
    count.innerHTML = plasticCount;
}, 10);
```